# Implement a way to categorise a question in terms of urgency / difficulty level

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I'm finding that there's a lot of extremely inexperienced developers posting questions here, which is totally fine, however I personally would prefer to be answering questions that solve problems that say a more experienced developer is facing or perhaps even reviewing already answered questions to just gain more knowledge.

I would propose that you could use your reputation to boost the priority of your question into different categories, this would also affect how much rep you would gain or lose for actions such as upvotes, downvotes and accepted answers. As well deleting a question wouldn't undo the damage it did to your rep (i.e. you wouldn't get it back).

This would overall improve the community as real problems would get more attention, and would also greatly deter someone from posting bad questions by spending rep, and encourage those with difficult questions to invest in their question. I realise there is a bounty system, but I feel it's under utilised and doesn't necessarily achieve the same thing I'm proposing here.

Comment: It's very simple, just put URGENT! DIFFICULT! in the title.

Answer (score 14):

All questions should be regarded at the same priority and/or urgency.  No one person's time is worth more than another's when using this asynchronous system.

There's also a lot of subjectivity around "real" problems, but I maintain, any time anyone wants to ask a question here that's suitable for the site, their problem is plenty "real", since they have to politely ask us to answer it.

Comment: It's not a matter of saying someone's time is better than someone else's. It's a matter of posing problems that are properly researched before asking, and also encourage asking proper questions.

Comment: @Augwa:  We already have systems which handle this - notably by suspending repeat offenders which don't take the system or community's warnings seriously.

Comment: I guess it only bothers me then when 9/10 questions I look at are terrible questions.

Comment: One way to effect change is to downvote more of those questions.  You say 9/10 of them you think are bad, but you've only downvoted 155 times in the last **three years**.

Comment: I just skip over a lot of bad questions, I could spend all day downvoting or all day answer questions. I think it's obvious which one is more productive.

Comment: @Augwa yes, I think it's obvious too: downvoting. There's plenty of people asking and answering, not enough *moderating*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe so in the absence of moderation then we need a better way for things to moderate themselves through natural selection. Down voting in theory is good, and it does filter out a lot of questions, but there's a lot that don't get downvoted for various reasons including my reason for not downvoting. I'd rather answer questions then be taking out the trash.

Comment: @Augwa and *that's why there's so much trash*. [Can't someone else do it?](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trash_of_the_Titans)

Comment: @Augwa that's the reason you have the ability to downvote. It's anonymous and it's easy to do. Flag and downvote **all** questions that aren't good enough to be on SO.