# Introduce an "urgent" tag

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, tags

There are a number of good [reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest) why you shouldn't add "This is really urgent!!!11" to the body of your question. It distracts users from what you're asking and may be considered rude and demanding of volunteers. However, there are certainly circumstances where users genuinly have an urgent question (e.g. when trying to recover from server failures, fixing a critical bug in a producting system, etc.). How do you view the addition of an [urgent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/urgent) tag, which users willing to deal with such urgent questions could monitor via their favorite tags? Bounties are not a suitable alternative, since you can't immediately add a bounty to a question - there's a 2 day 'grace period'.

Comment: [Relevant](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273150/has-there-been-any-discussion-for-allowing-urgent-bounties)

Comment: [Cross-site duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/6506/260312)

Comment: Urgent would be a meta tag and we've learned from experience those don't work well. Nobody is going to be an expert in Urgent.

Comment: I don't work for them, so they can do something that i'm not allowed to say with their urgency

Comment: Related: [Implement a way to categorise a question in terms of urgency / difficulty level](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347957/2675154).

Comment: If you are looking for urgent help on the internet, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: I'm sure such a tag would never be abused, right? No one would ever come up with the idea to add that tag to *all* their questions. (And please don't suggest having moderators police this).

Comment: @MartijnPieters you have better things to do?

Comment: Until this tag is created I suggest to add [urgent](http://stackoverflow.com/users?search=urgent) to your username.

Comment: We don't care if the request is urgent. That's not our problem, that's theirs.

Comment: 'Of course it's urgent - I've done no work and my assignment is due in tomorow!'

Comment: The idea that we are 'on call' to attempt to fix servers or production systems is just well...   words fail me :(

Comment: Not that this would stand a chance, but if it did, I'd be pretty happy to add [urgent] to my ignore list.

Comment: I think this is a great idea! I would love to point my downvote bot at the entire [tag:urgent] tag.

Comment: It's a good thing MSO posts don't effect reputation, because this question alone would have cost OP a mean -164 rep

Comment: Glad to see this declined as it would be abused like mad. If you have an urgent problem and its within the vendor's support for a product then try them, otherwise it is down to try and improve your search terms to find an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Answer (score 36):

Have you ever asked a question that you *didn't* think was urgent (or, at least, important)? Everyone wants a quick solution to their problem.

It's also a little unclear how you'd treat the question differently if it had that tag. I don't look for questions to answer based on the asker's perceived urgency of the question, but rather based on whether or not I'm likely to know the answer to them. For example, obviously I don't look for PHP questions because I don't know PHP, so I'd be unlikely to know the answer. I'm no more likely to search for an "urgent" PHP question than a non-urgent one.

However, I *do* typically monitor the C#, Java, Python, and Android tags because I actually know about those technologies. The "urgent" tag wouldn't make me more likely to find - or view - a particular question in those tags.

Tags are to organize questions by topic. You can be an expert in Java or PHP, but you can't be an expert in urgent questions. Personally, I wouldn't ever search by that tag.

I *would*, however, support allowing you to add bounties to urgent questions sooner.

**TL;DR** The point of tags is to organize questions by *topic*. "Urgent" isn't a topic. I seriously doubt that the tag would actually draw more attention to the question either.

Comment: Oh - I'm pretty sure that it would generate negative attention.

Comment: @ThingyWotsit Why did you think that?

Comment: @AlonEitan those who answer questions here in their free time dislike being given priorities by arrogant posters who think their question is more important then everyone else's.  A downvote is a common response, even before reading the body of the question.

Comment: @ThingyWotsit Oh! I thought you meant that this answer would generate negative attention, silly me. I totally agree with what you say

Comment: *I would, however, support allowing you to add bounties to urgent questions sooner.* Seems like it would be a waste of rep since new questions are already added to the top of the "newest" list and any clarifying edits bumps them to the top of the "active" list. I'm not sure allowing people to spend rep to advertise a question while it's still highly visible would actually be helpful.

Answer (score 20):

By far the largest problem with such a tag is not its potential for abuse, that this is not what tags are for, or that it'll almost certainly be be ineffective, but that the very idea of "urgent questions" presumes that the community somehow has an obligation to provide an answer.

"Could you please answer this question on a voluntary basis if you feel like it, and oh it's urgent and I need an answer ASAP" is rather silly, but that is what such a tag would mean. Either the "voluntary basis" is false, or the "urgent" loses its meaning, and I think everyone realises  only one of those two options is viable.

Comment: Yes, and _ASAP_ / _urgent_ references in such questions usually attract massive revenge-downvotes (This is how I see those downvotes anyway)

Comment: @AlonEitan maybe that would save time, have an urgent tag but have it automatically put 10 or so downvotes on the question.

Comment: @RobertLongson Now that's a proper suggestion!

Comment: Well, you need a proper scale.  I agree with -10 for urgent, (-20 for URGENT!'), and suggest -5 for ASAP.

Comment: Such a shame we're 16 days too late to really flesh this out and see how far we could take it.

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure they are still dancing their way to a solution for their urgent questions